# Ref & Key issues when mock testing with objectify entity models

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I am not sure if I should just flat out not be doing this but I am usually used to mocking a lot of areas of my application and am running into issues when I use Ref and Keys inside of my entities.

I have followed the pattern in the [docs](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities) where you use a ref in the entity but you mask the ref so you can get access to the driver object it references like so:

```
@Entity
class Car {
    @Id Long id;
    @Load Ref<Person> driver;    // Person is an @Entity

    public Person getDriver() { return driver.get(); }
    public void setDriver(Person value) { driver = Ref.create(value); }
}
```

My particular scenario is working with an importer where I am parsing xml and building up my entities ready to save them.  As my unit tests are only actually testing the import and parsing of the xml I mock out my dao implementations so that I am not actually using the datastore.

I then run into issues when I have called setDriver which just creates a Ref object.  I then use the getDriver method which will return null as the Ref.get has a direct dependency on the datastore.

Has anyone ever come across this problem and is there any way to create a mock Ref object?  I was considering not having a direct reference to Ref in my entity and instead having a reference to a helper class that can provide a Ref that I have control over in my tests?

Answer (score 3):

The short list of options are:

1. Use PowerMock
2. Add your own RefCreator object
3. Use the fake datastore instead of mocking

I never mock the datastore tier. The local unit testing harness is one of the best things about GAE; it gives you a fully functional fake of the datastore instead:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting

Comment: could you elaborate on how PowerMock would need to be used?

Comment: PowerMock can mock static methods. That said, it's a horrible idea. Don't mock Ref, just use the real thing with the fake datastore that Google provides. It's great.

Answer (score 0):

I wrap the Ref in a Guava Supplier to avoid the dependency on Objectify during unit testing of my pojos. The suppliers are translated to a datastore Key in a similar manner as Ref.

This class is mostly copied from the Objectify [RefTranslatorFactory](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/objectify/impl/translate/RefTranslatorFactory.java):

```
public class RefSupplierTranslatorFactory
    extends ValueTranslatorFactory<Supplier<?>, com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key> {
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public RefSupplierTranslatorFactory() {
    super((Class) Supplier.class);
}

@Override
protected ValueTranslator<Supplier<?>, com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key> createValueTranslator(
        TypeKey<Supplier<?>> tk, CreateContext ctx, Path path) {

    final LoadConditions loadConditions = new LoadConditions(tk.getAnnotation(Load.class));

    return new ValueTranslator<Supplier<?>, com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key>(
            com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.class) {

        @Override
        protected Supplier<?> loadValue(com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key value, LoadContext ctx, Path path)
                throws SkipException {
            Ref<Object> ref = ctx.loadRef(Key.create(value), loadConditions);
            return new RefSupplier(ref);
        }

        @Override
        protected com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key saveValue(Supplier<?> value, boolean index,
                SaveContext ctx, Path path) throws SkipException {
            return ctx.saveRef(Ref.create(value.get()), loadConditions);
        }
    };
}

public static class RefSupplier
        implements Serializable, Supplier<Object> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    final private Ref<?> ref;

    public RefSupplier(Ref<?> ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    @Override
    public Object get() {
        return ref.get();
    }

}
}
```

Say I have the following Pojos:

```
@Entity
public static class CarWithSupplier {
    @Id
    Long id;
    Supplier<SteeringWheel> steeringWheel;
    List<Supplier<Tire>> tires;
}

@Entity
public static class SteeringWheel {
    @Id
    Long id;
}

@Entity
public static class Tire {
    @Id
    Long id;
}
```

I am able to run a unit test without dependency on Objectify:

```
@Test
public void testSupplier() {
    CarWithSupplier car = carWithSupplier();
    assertNotNull(car.steeringWheel);
    assertNotNull(car.tires);
    assertEquals(2, car.tires.size());
}

protected CarWithSupplier carWithSupplier() {
    CarWithSupplier car = new CarWithSupplier();
    car.steeringWheel = Suppliers.ofInstance(steeringWheel());
    final Supplier<Tire> leftFrontTire = Suppliers.ofInstance(tire());
    final Supplier<Tire> rightFrontTire = Suppliers.ofInstance(tire());
    car.tires = ImmutableList.of(leftFrontTire, rightFrontTire);
    return car;
}
```

Extending the unit test, but setting up the necessary objectify resources during test setup I am able to get the same unit test to run against the datastore:

```
@Before
public void setUpObjectify() throws Exception {
    helper.setUp();
    closeable = ObjectifyService.begin();
    final ObjectifyFactory factory = ObjectifyService.factory();
    factory.getTranslators().add(new RefSupplierTranslatorFactory());
    factory.register(CarWithSupplier.class);
    factory.register(SteeringWheel.class);
    factory.register(Tire.class);
}

@Override
protected CarWithSupplier carWithSupplier() {
    final CarWithSupplier car = super.carWithSupplier();
    final Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.ofy();
    Key<CarWithSupplier> key = ofy.save().entity(car).now();
    return ofy.load().key(key).now();
}

@Override
protected Tire tire() {
    final Tire tire = super.tire();
    ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entity(tire).now();
    return tire;
}

@Override
protected SteeringWheel steeringWheel() {
    final SteeringWheel steeringWheel = super.steeringWheel();
    ObjectifyService.ofy().save().entity(steeringWheel).now();
    return steeringWheel;
}
```

Unit testing of my pojos is valuable since they are populated initially using the JSON response from third party web API services (using Gson).  I find it valuable to separate testing of Gson parsing from testing objectify datastore function. I later test them altogether during integration testing.

I haven't put this through extensive use yet so I welcome input from @stickfigure if this may cause issues or otherwise take away advantages of using Ref directly.

Comment: I found an Entity that implements Supplier causes problems (clash with ClassTranslatorFactory).  This problem could be avoided by providing a subinterface of Supplier as the translation type, but in my case I removed Supplier from the violating entity.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [code to mock Objectify's `Key` and `Ref` classes here](https://github.com/presentco/present-engine/blob/master/src/main/java/present/objectify/MockObjectify.java).

To use:

```
Ref<MyEntity> ref = MockObjectify.ref(myEntity);
```

Here's the source:

```
package present.objectify;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;
import com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy;
import com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Ref;
import com.googlecode.objectify.impl.KeyMetadata;
import com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Path;
import com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.CreateContext;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import present.engine.Caches;

/**
 * Creates Objectify mocks.
 *
 * @author Bob Lee
 */
public class MockObjectify {

  /** Creates a reference to the given instance. */
  public static <T> Ref<T> ref(T instance) {
    return new Ref<T>() {
      @Override public T get() {
        return instance;
      }

      @Override public boolean isLoaded() {
        return true;
      }

      @Override public Key<T> key() {
        return MockObjectify.key(instance);
      }
    };
  }

  /** Creates a key with a mock application ID. */
  public static <T> Key<T> key(T instance) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    KeyMetadata<T> metadata = (KeyMetadata<T>) keyMetadatas.getUnchecked(instance.getClass());
    return inMockEnvironment(() -> Key.create(metadata.getRawKey(instance)));
  }

  /** Creates a key with a mock application ID. */
  public static <T> Key<T> key(Class<? extends T> kindClass, long id) {
    KeyMetadata<T> metadata = keyMetadata(kindClass);
    return inMockEnvironment(() -> Key.create(KeyFactory.createKey(metadata.getKind(), id)));
  }

  /** Creates a key with a mock application ID. */
  public static <T> Key<T> key(Class<? extends T> kindClass, String name) {
    KeyMetadata<T> metadata = keyMetadata(kindClass);
    return inMockEnvironment(() -> Key.create(KeyFactory.createKey(metadata.getKind(), name)));
  }

  /** Creates a key with a mock application ID. */
  public static <T> Key<T> key(Key<?> parent, Class<? extends T> kindClass, long id) {
    KeyMetadata<T> metadata = keyMetadata(kindClass);
    return inMockEnvironment(() -> Key.create(KeyFactory.createKey(parent.getRaw(), metadata.getKind(), id)));
  }

  /** Creates a key with a mock application ID. */
  public static <T> Key<T> key(Key<?> parent, Class<? extends T> kindClass, String name) {
    KeyMetadata<T> metadata = keyMetadata(kindClass);
    return inMockEnvironment(() -> Key.create(KeyFactory.createKey(parent.getRaw(), metadata.getKind(), name)));
  }

  private static final ObjectifyFactory factory = new ObjectifyFactory();

  private static final LoadingCache<Class<?>, KeyMetadata<?>> keyMetadatas = Caches.create(
      type -> new KeyMetadata<>(type, new CreateContext(factory), Path.root()));

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static <T> KeyMetadata<T> keyMetadata(Class<? extends T> clazz) {
    return (KeyMetadata<T>) keyMetadatas.getUnchecked(clazz);
  }

  private static <T> T inMockEnvironment(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    ApiProxy.Environment original = ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment();
    try {
      ApiProxy.setEnvironmentForCurrentThread(mockEnvironment);
      return supplier.get();
    } finally {
      ApiProxy.setEnvironmentForCurrentThread(original);
    }
  }

  private static final ApiProxy.Environment mockEnvironment = new ApiProxy.Environment() {
    @Override public String getAppId() {
      return "mock";
    }

    @Override public String getModuleId() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override public String getVersionId() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override public String getEmail() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override public boolean isLoggedIn() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override public boolean isAdmin() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override public String getAuthDomain() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override public String getRequestNamespace() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
      return Collections.emptyMap();
    }

    @Override public long getRemainingMillis() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
  };
}
```